# How to use the console command DbAcl in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: console, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to do my first steps with `CakePHP 2` `console` with `Leopard` and `XAMPP` but I get many problems which are not clear to me.

In the [CakePHP 2.0 guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html?highlight=acl#AclComponent) is written i need to setup correctly `/app/Config/database.php to` be sure it works, then I've tested it with an user registration and everything works.

Then I've read I can call the command via shell:

```
$ cake schema create DbAcl
```

This doesn't work because I must write the `right path` to the console app, then:

```
$ /Users/username/.../site.com/lib/Cake/Console/cake schema create DbAcl
```

After did that I get this error:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : username
Path: /Users/username/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cake Schema Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/username/Config/Schema/db_acl.php could not be loaded
iMac-Name:~ username$
```

My CakePHP installation is located in the folder `site.com`:

```
site.com/app
site.com/lib
site.com/plugins
site.com/vendors
site.com/etc.
```

So I did this to change the CakePHP folder to the installation folder named `site.com`

```
$ /Users/username/.../site.com/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app /Users/.../site.com
```

Now I get this message:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : site.com
Path: /Users/.../public_html/site.com/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

-app: site.com
-working: /Users/.../site.com
-root: /Users/.../public_html
-core: /Users/.../site.com/lib
```

Now if I write

```
$ /Users/username/.../site.com/lib/Cake/Console/cake schema create DbAcl
```

I get the wrong original path again with a different error:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : username
Path: /Users/username/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cake Schema Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/username/Config/Schema/db_acl.php could not be loaded
```

How can I fix the path correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strange thing, if I set user folder first, it works correctly:

```
$ cd folder/webserver/public_html/cake-app-folder
$ sudo lib/Cake/Console/cake schema DbAcl
```

in this way it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

The real reason why many people that want to use Cakephp ACL system face this problem is that they ignore the right position where they should be before execute this command.

If you notice the error message, it says : "/Users/username/Config/Schema/db_acl.php could not be loaded".
Which is normal, actually the db_acl.php file is located in /Users/username/app/Config/Schema/db_acl.php

==> To let cakePhp fetch the file from the right place you have to be positioned in the app folder of your cake project before executing the command (cd folder/webserver/public_html/cake-app-folder in your case or c:\wamp\www\cakeTest\app for a windows project case)

Dr.Lotfi

Coopa' easy'